# How can i avoid new line at the end of the file?

Tags: python, file, split

i need to use

```
for line in doc.split('\n'):
```

and do some operation on each line but i got at the end of the file
empty line as i think it split a new line every time ! how can i avoid this problem ?

Comment: Are you asking how you can avoid that `doc` contains an empty line at the end?

Comment: Just open the file and read it one line at a time.  `with open(fname) as f: for line in f.read()`.    See Riccardo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please rephrase your question, since it is not very clear.

Anyway, if you are working with a text file you can just use:

```
with open("path_to_soruce_textfile", "r") as src, open("path_to_dest_textfile", "w") as dst:
    for line in src.readlines():            # this gives you a list of lines with each line finishing with \n
       processed_line = modidy(line)
       dst.write(processed_line)            # make sure \n is at the end of each line when you write

# the file is automatically closed
```